# Representation of tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

If we take $u\in X\otimes Y$ then we can find $\{x_{i}\}_{i=1...n}$ and $\{y_{i}\}_{i=1...n}$ linear independent such that $u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\otimes y_{i}.$ 
It is true for tensor product of three or greater number elements?
For example is there exist $\{x_{i}\}_{i=1...n}$, $\{y_{i}\}_{i=1...n}$, $\{z_{i}\}_{i=1...n}$ linear independent such that $x\otimes y\otimes z=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\otimes y_{i} \otimes z_{i}?$

Comment: Any remarks about this?

Comment: In the case you have written, it is immediate if you take $n=1$ and $x_1 = x, y_1 = y, z_1 = z$. Did you mean, for any $u \in X \otimes Y \otimes Z$?